# jquery.ez-plus redimensionar o quadro do zoom

Tags: jquery

Tenho o seguinte código

```
<div class='fotosPlanos'>
  <img 
      class='elevate-image' 
      src='_img/_fotos/corsa.jpg'
      data-zoom-image='_img/_fotos/corsa.jpg'
  />
</div>

<script> 
    $('.elevate-image').ezPlus({
    zoomType: 'inner',
    cursor: 'crosshair'     
  });
</script>
```

Ele cria uma caixa de zoom sobre a imagem recipiente.

Mas o problema é que à medida que reduzimos o tamanho da tela e consequentemente o tamanho da imagem, a caixa de zoom deveria também reduzir e não reduz.

Pode ser visto em

http://funerariasaopedro.net.br/novo/showroom.php

Como fazer para atrelar o tamanho da caixa de zoom ao tamanho da imagem com o plugin ez-plu?

Comment: É, parece que não tem jeito. Pois o plugin é jQuery e não roda como o css em tempo de execução. Logo, ao reduzir as dimensões do navegador e consequentemente a imagem, o plugin não acompanha e após dar um refresh aí então ele pega a resolução  ajusta o zoom à caixa da imagem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inicie o plugin dentro de um evento `load` e `resize`. No `load` ele iniciará quando a página for carregada e no `resize` irá atualizar o plugin quando houver redimensionamento da tela, ajustando as dimensões da janela do zoom.

**Exemplo:**

```js
$(window).on("load resize", function(){
   $('.elevate-image').ezPlus({
       zoomType: 'inner',
       cursor: 'crosshair'
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://dvdteste.websiteseguro.com/jquery.ez-plus.js"></script>
<div class='fotosPlanos' style="width: 100%; max-width: 600px;">
  <img style="width: 100%;" 
      class='elevate-image' 
      src='https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg'
      data-zoom-image='http://dvdteste.hospedagemdesites.ws/zoom2.jpg'
  />
</div>
```

Comment: Perfeito! muito obrigado: era exatamente isso!